# How to save a string as a character in CSV in R, so that it doesn't covert into scientific notation when i open in excel?

Tags: r, excel, csv

I'm trying to save a String '**24E30**' in a CSV (*This is just an example i have thousands like this*)

```
db<-data.frame(empid=c("24E30","19E01","135E4","21E20"))
```

For this particular column '**empid**' i tried:

```
db$empid<-as.character(db$empid)
write.csv(db,"test.csv")
```

When i tried to open this CSV file in excel i saw:

[image]

and in R, i see:

```
read.csv("test.csv")

     X    empid
1 1 2.40e+31
2 2 1.90e+02
3 3 1.35e+06
4 4 2.10e+21
```

Is there any encoding or any other function, which i can 
 use to ignore this scientific notation and retain the original character value i.e. *("24E30","19E01","135E4","21E20")*.

A concrete solution would be really appreciated!

Comment: You may enter this as plain text to avoid conversion.

Comment: `read.csv("test.csv", colClasses = "character")`

Comment: @cuttlefish44 Thanks, and how to solve the same for Excel?

Comment: @J.Chomel : Thanks, could you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to open it in Excel as text:

1. First rename your file with `.txt` extension
2. Then open this file in Excel: it brings up the import wizard:

   a. choose fixed width + next

   b. set the column breaks e.g.:
   [image] + next

   c. select your column and define its type: ***`text`***
   [image] + finish

= worked for me.

Comment: it separates into different columns.. but Thanks for the solution :)

Comment: You can remove column separators by double-clicking them in the wizard.